# How do I add `System.Dynamic` to my project?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic-language-runtime

I am new to C# 4, especially the `dynamic` keyword. I have seen quite a number of tutorials and wish to try it out myself using VS 2012 Ultimate (MSDN).

Unfortunately I cannot seem to find `System.Dynamic` and cannot add a reference to it either. May I know where I can find the DLL for `System.Dynamic` and what I might have done wrong?

By default, VS 2012 already targets Fx 4.5, and `System.Core` is added as a reference.

The `dynamic` keyword is so common that when searching in Google yield a lot of un-related results.

Comment: My guess is that you've created a project type which doesn't target .NET 4 or higher. What kind of project are you using, and what version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Agree with Jon.  Check your project properties, make sure you're targeting .NET 4.0 or higher (and not the `client profile` option...)

Answer (score 9):

1. Make sure you are targeting the .NET Framework version 4 or later.
2. Ensure your project references the `System.Core` assembly.
3. You will find the types and functionality of `System.Dynamic` in that assembly. Add the following line to your code files:

   ```
   using System.Dynamic;
   ```

[image: <code>System.Dynamic</code> is found in <code>System.Core.dll</code>]

**P.S.:** In C#, in order for the `dynamic` keyword to work properly, you also need to reference the `Microsoft.CSharp` assembly. This assembly contains the late-binding functionality necessary for `dynamic`.

Comment: Thanks. My project is already targeting Framework 4.5, I have System.Core in my reference, but I can't find/add System.Dynamic into my reference. I am using VS2012 ultimate MSDN edition.

Comment: You cannot add `System.Dynamic` as a reference because it is not an assembly; it's a *namespace*. The relevant assembly, for which you need a reference, is `System.Core`. What you need to do is to put a `using System.Dynamic;` directive at the start of your source code file(s).

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you want to search for documentation add `msdn`. Like [`msdn system.dynamic`](https://www.google.com/search?q=msdn%20system.dynamic)

You will find all the documentation you need.

[System.Dynamic at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx)

```
Namespace:  System.Dynamic
Assembly:  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)
```

The DLL is `System.Core`. Adding a reference to it will allow you to use the namespace `System.Dynamic`.